# Does Form 8938 have to be signed?

Tags: united-states, taxes

Unless I'm blind, I don't see any place on Form 8938 for a signature. As it's submitted with the normal tax return, presumably the signature on the 1040 covers this - correct?

Answer (score 1):

That is correct. The form is attached as an additional schedule to your tax return (form 1040) and is considered an integral part of it. Your signature on the form 1040 (and the jurat on it) covers also the attached form 8938.